# JSF templating beginner's question

Tags: jsf

I belong to Asp.Net but just starting to learn JSF. I wanted to know whether all features of MasterPage are available in JSF templating? I mean say suppose i have a menu in template, and based on roles menu changes. If the Admin logs in, he will get to show more options and if general user logs in he will get to see less options. Now i have a managed bean for my "real" page(not template). How do i use this managed bean to toggle my control in template on and Off?

Comment: Since you're new to JSF, I'd be curious why you've chosen for JSFTemplating. Why didn't you just go ahead with "plain" Facelets?

Comment: Hi BalusC,
I want something similar to MasterPage in Asp.Net. I am using Facelets only. How can i achieve this functionality in facelets? If you can point me to some tutorial or if you can give me brief overview i would be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do pretty much all in JSF/Facelets as you could do in ASP MasterPages. You can use the `rendered` attribute of any JSF component to toggle whether the component needs to be rendered in the view. It accepts a boolean expression which will cause the component (and all its children) to be shown when `true`, otherwise completely hidden when `false`. Here are several examples:

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.intValue > 10}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.objectValue == null}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue != 'someValue'}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!bean.booleanValue && bean.intValue != 0}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue == 'oneValue' || bean.stringValue == 'anotherValue'}" />
```

To learn more about JSF/Facelets, I recommend to go through Sun's own JSF tutorial in the [Java EE 6 tutorial part II chapters 4-9](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html) and [Marty Hall's Coreservlets.com tutorials](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial on JSF templating:

[**JSF 2 Tutorials - Templating**](http://tutslink.blogspot.com/2012/04/understanding-jsf-part-4-templating.html)

In order to customize what different user roles will see just use **rendered** attribute.